# sequence of sets equivalence

Tags: measure-theory

We're asked to show $\limsup \{A_n \bigcup B_n\}$ = $\limsup A_n \bigcup \limsup B_n$.

Thus to prove equivalence I try the following using the definitions of lim sup of set sequences:

1. left to right:

$$\limsup A_n \bigcup B_n  \,=\,  \bigcap \bigcup_{k=n} A_k \bigcup B_k  \quad\quad [1]$$

Thus $\exists$ some $k \geq n$ such that if $\omega \in [1]$ then $\omega$ is either in $\bigcup A_k$ or $\bigcup B_k$ $\implies$ $\omega \in$ $\limsup A_n \bigcup \limsup B_n$.

2. right to left

$$\limsup A_n \bigcup \limsup B_n \,=\,  \left(\bigcap \bigcup_{k=n} A_k\right) \bigcup \left(\bigcap \bigcup_{k=n} B_k\right) \quad\quad [2]$$

There $\exists \,k \geq n$ such that if $\omega \in [2] \implies \omega \in [1]$ since $\omega$ is in either $\bigcup A_k$ or $ \bigcup B_k$ $\forall k >= n.$